# Using Javascript to take select input and use data in another section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, select

I have a section of html that allows an user to select a billing term in a drop down option. I need to write javascript to take the value of the selected option and use it for a different section.

My HTML:

```
<div class="payment-term">
   <label>Billing period:</label>
   <select id="billing-price" name="billing-term" class="selectpicker">
     <option value="200">12 Months: $200/mo. (Save 20%)</option>
     <option value="250">1 Month: $250/mo.</option>
   </select>
</div>
<div class="card-charge-info">
    Your card will be charged $<span id="payment-total"></span> now, and your subscription will bill $<span id="payment-total"></span> every month thereafter. You can cancel or change plans anytime.
</div>
```

My Javascript that I have started:

```
var e = document.getElementById("#payment-term");
var stringPmt = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

My JSFIDDLE that I started: http://jsfiddle.net/rynslmns/DcJ4f/1/

Comment: You can't have the same `id` more than once.

Comment: @Skwal I understand that, I was doing it to make it easier to understand what I was trying to do. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach an event to your select box, and update both prices separately (with their own id's).

```
var select = document.getElementById('billing-price');
select.addEventListener('change', updatePrice, false);

function updatePrice(e) {
    var price = select.value;
    document.getElementById('payment-total').innerText = price;
    document.getElementById('payment-rebill').innerText = price;   
}
```

Here's your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DcJ4f/2/

Comment: It works exactly as I have asked for, however, if I wanted to prevent the '1-month' option from updating the #payment-rebill span, would that be possible?

Comment: you can wrap it into `if (price != 250){ //... }` or so

Comment: I did this:

`if (price == select.options[2].value){
     document.getElementById('payment-rebill').innerText = 0;
     } else {
     document.getElementById('payment-rebill').innerText = price;
     }`

Not sure if it's 'good' code but it works.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the selected value

```
var e = document.getElementById("billing-price").value;
```